# Fitting a Gaussian Mixture Model to a very simple distribution

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, gaussian

I have a simple discrete distribution that I keep in a dataframe:

```
dist_df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0],
                        'y': [ 780, 1708, 10028, 15696, 10779]})
```

I just want to fit a gaussian mixture model from sklearn to this, and obtain how many gaussians I need, their parameters and the probabilities that each element belongs to each gaussian. But first, I just want to fit and predict my distribution. I looked on the sklearn documentation, but the only examples I found are half a page code, that I really don't understand. This should be very simple, but I am trying to understand how it works by applying it to this.

Comment: @yatu I don't get it ? I just want to fit a sklearn.gmm model to a tiny dataframe.

Comment: Your arrays are not the same length (`x` has `6` values, `y` has `5`).

Comment: You need to specify the number of components to use beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how. Note that the number of components cannot exceed the number of observations, in this case `6`. You can read more [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html):

```
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture as GMM

number_of_components = 2 # specify the number of components here
gmm = GMM(n_components=number_of_components).fit(dist_df)
```